# Types option is not available for image asset catalog in xcode inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, assets, xcode7.3, xcasset

I am trying to use .pdf image in xcode asset catalog. So all @1x, @2x, @3x images will be generated by the xcode in build time.

The problem I am facing is i am not able to find the type option in the inspector in xcode 7.3. Only scale factor is available instead of types[image] If i use scale factor image is not retrieved

Comment: if you pdf is a single vector , it does not comes with `@1x, @2x, @3x`

Comment: use render as original Image

Comment: So single vector option in xcode 7.3 is equivalent to vector option? if so render as original image should be used to get the all @X images?

Comment: if you use original image it comes perfectly in visibility